# Efficiently calculating the total time a cell is occupied by comparing the line segments within a cell and their speed

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, movement-data

I have a 1km square grid and what I want to do find the total length of all line segment within that cell and multiply it by each individual lines speed variable to get a total time occupied value to populate into a column in the grid dataset. I am having a hard time explaining it with words so using the example below Grid 1 should be equal (0.54x5)+(0.65x8)= 7.9 and Cell 2 should equal 0.28x2=0.56 and so on for each cell in the grid.

[image: My Sample Grid]

Each cell should only be looking at the line length within it, so not the total length of the intersecting line.

I have considered looping through the grid, clipping the lines into a geodataframe, then doing the math, then append it to the column but I have a huge grid and the loop takes a very long time.

I also considered interpolating points along the line based on the speed; the point would represent where the object was at a given hour of its journey. Then using the spatial join count function I would get a rough metric of object time within each grid. Interpolating points based on a column value for that row is turning out to be tricky so I thought I would ask if there was a means of doing it as I outlined above.

Comment: How many polygons and lines are there?

Comment: Do you have to original raw point data with timestamps? Is it a strict requirement to use the speed value from the dataset column or would it be ok to use computed speed (based on consecutive points)?

Comment: 4.8million grid cells and I think somewhere around 600000 tracks.

Comment: I am compiling the point data you suggest as we speak. QGIS is running a point along geometry where the distance parameter is set to $length/speed in meters and meters per minute. This should generate a point along the line at 1min intervals. When that is done a count of points in each cell should provide a close approximation of how many minutes any given cell is occupied by travelers along those routes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like the problem has been resolved. Feel free to ask a new question if some aspects are still unanswered.

Comment: Is there a way we could leave the original answer here, I would like to work on this more.. I don't see how it is unclear or off topic; it deals with computing information from geographic information.